# Input field won't change in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change the input field on forms but I can't change anything. I need help to see what I did wrong on the 'this.changeNameHandler'.

```
class UApt extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            details: [],
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            appointmentName: ''
        }
        this.changeNameHandler = this.changeNameHandler.bind(this);
    }
   
    
    changeNameHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({ appointmentName: event.target.value });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label> Name: </label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder="Name" 
                                name="appointmentName" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.details.appointmentName} 
                                onChange={this.changeNameHandler} />
                    </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is here: `value={this.state.details.appointmentName} `. appoinmentName is not in the details array. Therefore, the value does not change.

Comment: so my value is stored in `this.state.details.appointmentName`, how should I set it so that `this.state.appointName` contains that value

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of your form input to this

```js
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label> Name: </label>
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder="Name" 
                                name="appointmentName" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.appointmentName} 
                                onChange={this.changeNameHandler} />
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`value={this.state.details.appointmentName}`

with

`value={this.state.appointmentName}`!

It looks like you are assigning a wrong state item to the value.

Answer (score 0):

change input value from
{this.state.details.appointmentName}
to
{this.state.details.appointmentName}

and also you missed the closing tag for a div with className = "form-group"